# Sending messages(notification) to a group - Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, push-notification

I am writing an android application in which i need to send a notification to a group of users.

I have two group of users in the database. If a user press a button "Notify Group 1" in the android app , i need to send the notification to all the group 1 users. How i implement this logic? I think the same logic is using in the group chat .

Can you provide me the sample code for android and server side?

Thanks..
Zacharia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Android Cloud to Device Messaging](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=ko-KR) is the best approach, as you can easily integrate it with MySQL and PhP, having the necessary tools to send message over internet.

You can group users according to your need:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gcm_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gcm_regid` text,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Source - [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Here you have a typical example with a Java class that send message over internet with [Google cloud](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#c2dm_sendmessage):

```
public class MessageUtil {
      private final static String AUTH = "authentication";

      private static final String UPDATE_CLIENT_AUTH = "Update-Client-Auth";

      public static final String PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";

      public static final String PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE = "delay_while_idle";

      public static final String PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY = "collapse_key";

      private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

      public static int sendMessage(String auth_token, String registrationId,
          String message) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append(PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID).append("=")
            .append(registrationId);
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append(PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY).append("=")
            .append("0");
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=")
            .append(URLEncoder.encode(message, UTF8));

        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        // Hit the dm URL.

        URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
        HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
            Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="
            + auth_token);

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        return responseCode;
      }

      private static class CustomizedHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
        }
      }
 }
```

To wrap it up, then you can integrate you query using MySQL with PhP to achieve what you want. Here you have the server side with the [PhP example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/):

```
send_message.php
<?php
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Here you find some additional examples that might come in hand, including logic of the system:

- [Google cloud messaging sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408718/google-cloud-messaging-sample)
- [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging GCM - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)
- [Google Cloud Messaging For Android (GCM) Simple Tutorial](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/)
- [Google Cloud Messaging GCM for Android and Push Notifications](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)

Taking from here you can get your App with the features you have in mind.

Comment: i need to send the message by internet not by SMS... also the users list are in the server database